# Access Canvas Elements without an id

Tags: canvas, html5-canvas, developer-tools, web-inspector

Short story: How do you access the buttons inside a canvas that doesn't have an id with javascript or jquery? (The canvas element is inside a div that has an id if that helps).

Long story: I searched everywhere on google and I still can't find a solution. Is there an extension for a canvas inspector? I know there was one on chrome before but then it got removed. Is the only option to restore a previous chrome version? I couldn't find any other github extensions that allow canvas inspecting.

Comment: A button inside a canvas is not really a button -- it is a picture of a button painted on the canvas. If you just have one big button filling the canvas you can set an id on the canvas and subscribe to common events on the canvas - `myCanvas.on('click',...)`, etc. If you have multiple buttons on one canvas then you must listen for mouse events and individually hit-test each button drawing.

Comment: But say I'm trying to figure out what the events are in the canvas, and the canvas I'm 'inspecting' doesn't even have an id.

Comment: You can ask the DOM to give you a list of all canvas elements on the page with `document.querySelectorAll`. All canvas elements support the [same basic events](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement) as other elements. **Again, anything drawn on canvas is just painted pixels** so you can't "inspect" anything on the canvas aside from the rgba values of each pixel. You can get an array of the canvas's rgba pixel data using: `getImageData`.

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATE**

First of all, if your canvas does not have an id then you need to give it one. If you cannot give it one, you can use [Child Nodes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/childNodes)

**END UPDATE**

**UPDATE 2**

A better way to select a canvas within a div is by using `document.querySelector()` in which you can use a CSS selector to get the canvas like this:`document.querySelector("#divid canvas")`. It returns the first possible element. Thank you markE for showing me that

**END UPDATE 2**

If you can set an event listener on the canvas to get the coordinates of the mouse, you can see if you clicked the button.

I use `canvas.getBoundingClientRect()` to get the offset from the page, especially useful if you need to scroll somewhere.

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById("mycanvas");
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
ctx.fillRect(10, 20, 100, 100);
canvas.addEventListener("click", buttonClick, false);
function buttonClick(e) {
  alert("You clicked the canvas");
  if (e.clientX - canvas.getBoundingClientRect().left >= 10 && e.clientX - canvas.getBoundingClientRect().left <= 110) {
    if (e.clientY - canvas.getBoundingClientRect().top >= 20 && e.clientY - canvas.getBoundingClientRect().top <= 120) {
      alert("You clicked the button");
      }
    }
  }
```

```html
<canvas id="mycanvas" width="250" height="250" style="border: 1px solid orange;"></canvas>
```

Comment: Here's how to grab the unknown canvas inside the DIV with a known ID: `var canvas = document.querySelector("#knownDivID canvas")` ;-)

Comment: Sorry, did not know that, updating answer